# Date of the folder in Python

Tags: python

I am developing code in python that should compare the date of the files in the folder to the current date. But I Can't get dates of the files can you help me ?

Comment: The date they were created? The date they were last edited? What have you been trying?

Comment: `But I Can't get dates of the files` why not? What issues did you run into?

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the files with something like this:

```
import os.path, time
print("Created: %s" % time.ctime(os.path.getctime("filename.txt")))
```

to get the dates of the files.

to get the current date you could use

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print("Current Time =", current_time)
```

and then compare them in the format you want